# How to order alphabetically a MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaquery

i need to order alphabetically a ipod queue.

with the following code the songs are not ordered alphabetically

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

[musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:everything];

[self.musicPlayer play]
```

with the following code the song are ordered alphabetically , but it need more than 60seconds to load

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

everything = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

[everything setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingTitle];

NSArray *collections = [everything collections];

MPMediaItemCollection *firstCollection = [collections
objectAtIndex:0];

NSMutableArray *combinedMediaItems = [[firstCollection items]
mutableCopy];

for(int i = 1; i < [collections count]; i++) {

    NSArray *newMediaItems = [[collections objectAtIndex:i] items];

    [combinedMediaItems addObjectsFromArray: newMediaItems];

}

[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: [MPMediaItemCollection
collectionWithItems: (NSArray *) combinedMediaItems]];

[self.musicPlayer play];
```

Can you help me? thanks.

Comment: what if you ask for [everything items] from the query instead of collections ?